# How to apply active link in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  const location = useLocation();
  const { pathname } = location;
  const splitLocation = pathname.split("/");

  const active = splitLocation[1] === item.path ? "sidebar-item active" : "sidebar-item";
```

so my problem is the "sidebar-item active" is not applying when click on a link.

Comment: Well, that's because `splitLocation[1]` and `item.path` are different. Try `console.log`ging both of the values.

Comment: how to resolve that problem?

Comment: After `const splitLocation = pathname.split("/");` write a new line that has the following: `console.log(splitLocation[1], pathname);` then look at the console. See what the output is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.